# NetBeans - Add @author automatically to a class when code is changed

Tags: plugins, netbeans-8, author

How can I make NetBeans 8.1+ to add an [@author](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#@author) tag automatically to JavaDoc of a class that I edit?

Answer (score 1):

The closest to have this process automated in Netbeans is to run `Tools -> Analyze Javadoc` before a commit to the repository and tick all the blue (*modified*) and green (*new*) entries for missing javadoc for a class.  This process, however, will neither add `@author` tag if the comment for a class already exists, nor update the existing tag. Here is [the manual](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html#analyze-javadoc).

I'm not sure about the usefulness of automatically marking each file that was touched as authored by whoever touched it, though, which might be the reason why such feature isn't available. Does a class that changed 1% deserve a change of the author? What about 40%? What about reshuffling imports? and so on... I guess one could come up with an alternative solution such as to introduce `@lasteditor` or multiple `@author` or `@editor` tags but I'm still not convinced this would add much value.

`git blame` (`Team -> Show Annotations`), `git log` etc. seem to be more suited for the task of tracking down the authors and editors.

One alternative solution, at least for Maven projects, could be the [javadoc:fix](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html) goal of [Javadoc plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) but it would only ensure that each class' javadoc has the `@author` tag and nothing fancy beyond that:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <fixTags>author</fixTags>
        <force>true</force>
        <fixFieldComment>false</fixFieldComment>
        <fixMethodComment>false</fixMethodComment>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Ad usefulness - that's basically up to the team to figure out. Not all code is always covered by a SCM. And adding an author to the file is good for future editors because the previous, most likely, studied the file and can be asked about details. It's not about "claiming" the authorship, really. That's probably your assumption.

Comment: I was merely pointing out to what a Netbeans developer may be thinking when considering this feature, how the tool can determine that a change is significant enough in order to warrant the `@author` tag update, or should it care about it at all in which case, say, a simple typo fix would cause the update.Personally I think in the circumstances you described a separate readme or changlog document giving more context would work better than a creative use of the `@author` tag but as you said, that's for the team to decide.